# Using simple random sample for large number of data with confidence interval

Tags: confidence-interval, sampling, sample-size

I am trying to see if a sample that I might use is better compared to my current results. I have sets of large data, 220k in one sample and 400k in another. I am trying to see if I use a new source to replace my data if it will perform better and have less errors.  When I run a simple random sample with 95% confidence interval, the samples I get from a calculator are 343 for both. I realize I might not be understanding something fundamental. Why is the sample that same no matter how large 100k vs 200k, vs 400k only vary from 341-343 in terms of the sample I need to do an evaluation. I realize I have very large numbers I am comparing to but did not expect the sample number needed to come out the same.

Thanks

Comment: You are trying to replace a large sample by a smaller sample. What is not clear is what you mean for the smaller sample to 'perform better'. Are you fitting a model? Also a sample does not have confidence intervals. Not sure what software you are using, but you can very easily create a function that outputs the indices of a random sample of any size you like. For example: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html. Unless there are computational reasons, you should not throw away/reduce your data. Of course consider cleaning outliers first.